# add display field in html contact aspx

Tags: asp.net, html, contacts

I am relatively new to aspx. I'm trying to add a field in a contact page (which i have done) and display it in the resulting email ( which i am having trouble on). The email from the form still gets sent and all fields are displayed - but the particular field that i have added which is "ctrlDOP" does not display the text in the resulted email - it only displays #DOP#.

The contact.aspx and contact.xml pages and resulting email are below. Many thanks in advance.

--CONTACT.ASPX--

```
          </asp:Content>
        <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="content" runat="server">
        <h2>Job Attended / Completed</h2>

    <asp:MultiView ID="mvContactForm" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">

    <asp:View runat="server" ID="ContactForm" runat="server">
    <div class="form contact">
    <p>
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ctrlName">Job Number <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="ctrlName" ErrorMessage="required..." 
            CssClass="error" Display="Dynamic" /></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="ctrlName" runat="server" CssClass="txt required" />
    
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ctrlEmail">Model <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="ctrlEmail" ErrorMessage="required..."
            CssClass="error" Display="Dynamic" /></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="ctrlEmail" runat="server" CssClass="txt required" />
    
    </p>
    <p>
    <p>
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ctrlSubject">Serial <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="ctrlEmail" ErrorMessage="required..."
            CssClass="error" Display="Dynamic" /></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="ctrlSubject" runat="server" CssClass="txt required" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ctrlMessage">Report <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="ctrlMessage" ErrorMessage="required..."
            CssClass="error" Display="Dynamic" /></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="ctrlMessage" runat="server" CssClass="txt required" TextMode="MultiLine" />
    
    </p>
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ctrlDOP">DOP <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="ctrlDOP" ErrorMessage="required..."
            CssClass="error" Display="Dynamic" /></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="ctrlDOP" runat="server" CssClass="txt required" TextMode="SingleLine" />
    
    </p>

    <p class="commandBar">
        <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdSubmit" runat="server" CssClass=""
            OnClick="cmdSubmit_Click" SkinID="SubmitButton" AlternateText="Submit Enquiry" />
    </p>
    <p class="errorMessage"><asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />

    </p>
    <br class="clear" />
    </div>
    </asp:View>
        <asp:View runat="server" ID="ConfirmationMessage">
        <p>
        Your job info has been submitted.<br />
        Ensure the jobsheet makes it to the pigeon hole.
        </p>
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
    <br class="clear" />


    </asp:Content>
```

--CONTACT.XML--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Email>
<To>scotty@metroappliance.com.au</To>
<From>jobnotification@metroappliance.com.au</From>
<Subject>Job Notification: #SUBJECT#</Subject>
<Priority>Normal</Priority>
<Message format="HTML">
 <![CDATA[
        <html>
        <head>
        <title></title>
          <style type="text/css">
                * {font: 1em/1.5 Helvetica, Arial, 'Liberation Sans', FreeSans, sans-serif;}
                a, a:hover,a:visited,a:active{color:#2F9F49;}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body style="background-color:#00256e;">
            <div>
                <table border="0" width="600" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" style="background-color:#fff;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align=justify colspan="4">
                            <img src="#APP_ROOT#App_Themes/Default/images/email-header.jpg" alt="Metro Appliance">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p><b>Job attended by #NAME#.</b></p>
                            
                            <h4>#SUBJECT#</h4>
                            <h4>#DOP#</h4>
                            <p>#MESSAGE#</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>     
    ]]>
   </Message>
</Email>
```

--RESULTING EMAIL--

Job attended by jobnumber.
serial

## DOP

report

Again - I thank all in advance.

Comment: Since you say that the system is correctly generating the emails, could we see that part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the email generation code where you are replacing #DOP#, you haven't posted it but perhaps it's erroneously a zero instead of a O.

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys. Actually I'm not sure where the code is that generates the email. I am editing an existing site out of my comfort zone!! It started as a content (html and css) shuffle - but i have some other things i think the site needs... Can you pls advise where this code lives? I'm thinking web.config? I am a very quick learner - and willing to put in the time - so any help and pointers is very much appreciated.

Comment: The code for generating the email will not be in the web.config file. The Web.Config is used to store configuration information for the website and not code functionality. The best thing to do is debug the code and step through to where the email gets generated.